# background image quivering when animated

Tags: html, css, animation, background-image, keyframe

I was trying some animation when I stumbled upon a little problem : 
When I try to animate a div that has an image as a background, the said image seems to quiver, especially when it come to growing-shrinking a div from the center. Is there a way to prevent it from happening ? Or just an easier way to animate it ? Thanks a lot.

HTML

```
<div class = 'button'>
  <div class = 'background'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
  border : 5px solid black;
  border-radius : 50%;
  height : 150px;
  width : 150px;
  animation : bigger 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite;

}
.background{
  height : 100%;
  width : 100%;
  background : url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/69/69434.svg') no-repeat;
  background-size : 90%;
  background-position : center;

}
@keyframes bigger {
  0% {
    height : 150px;
    width : 150px;
  }
  100%{
    margin-left : -5px;
    margin-top : -5px;
    height : 160px;
    width : 160px;
  }
```

an exemple of the problem on a codepen : https://codepen.io/pen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's because of the amount of frames browsers render things in. If you change the timing, it works fine. Try to use transform: scale(x.x) instead. Check out this pen for more details.

```
@keyframes bigger {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1.1)
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: Oh hey, using Scale make it way smoother, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

There is something about the size and timing(frames). then the animate is jumping back to 0 to avoid that you should use `animation-direction: alternate-reverse` but its not quivering as mush in this code.

you can learn more about on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

```css
.button {
  width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  
  border : 5px solid black;
  border-radius : 50%;
  animation : example 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate-reverse;
 
}
.background{
  height : 100%;
  width : 100%;
  background : url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/69/69434.svg') no-repeat;
  background-size : 90%;
  background-position : center;

}
@keyframes example {
  0% {
    margin-left : 0;
    margin-top : 0;
    height : 150px;
    width : 150px;
  }
  100%{
    margin-left : -5px;
    margin-top : -5px;
    height : 170px;
    width : 170px;
  }
```

```html
<div class = 'button'>
  <div class = 'background'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll look into it. In the mean time, I was suggested to use scale rather than grow the div manually, thanks for the link though, it will come in handy !